# Inequality rules of random variables

Tags: random-variables

Hi is the following a true statement.

I have a random variable $P(X)$, and I need to find $P(1\leq X <\frac{3}{2})$.

So I was thinking whether the following statement is true:

$P(1\leq X <\frac{3}{2})=P(X=1)+P(1<X<\frac{3}{2})$.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely true. That is because the event $\{1 \leq X < \frac{3}{2}\}$ is a union of two disjoint events $\{ X = 1 \}$ and $\{ 1 < X < \frac{3}{2}\}$ (and the probability law $P$ is additive).

Comment: So if I have the following cumulative distributions function $F(X)=\begin{cases}0, x\leq 0\\ \frac{x}{3}, 0<x\leq 1\\ \frac{2x-1}{3},1<x\leq 2\\ 1, x>2 \end{cases}$ means that. $P(1<X\leq \frac{3}{2})=P(1<X< \frac{3}{2})+P(X=1)=P(1<X< \frac{3}{2})=F(\frac{3}{2})-F(1)$

Comment: Notice that your CDF defines a continuous distribution and consequently $P(X = 1) = 0$. (Or simply, $P(X = 1) = F(1) - F(1^-) = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} = 0$.) So, Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you meant "random variable $X$".

Yes, that is true, because probability (measure) is a measure, hence it must satisfy countable aditivity - in symbols (without exact details), let $\{A_i\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ be the set of pairwise disjoint measurable sets and $P$ be the probability measure. Then $P(\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} P(A_i)$.

This also applies to finite disjoint union, because $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n}A_i = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \cdots$.

And this applies to your situation, because $\{1 \leq X < 3/2 \} = \{X = 1\} \cup \{1 < X < 3/2\}$ and $\{X = 1 \} \cap \{1 < X < 3/2\} = \emptyset$.